# Get the position after click on button in a list view

Tags: android

I've that in my Adapter :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)   
        {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);          
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text01 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text01); 
            ((Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListButonPlus)).setOnClickListener(this);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();         
        }   
            return convertView;
        }
```

And  that :

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "pouette",1000).show();
}
```

And I try t get the position of the item who contains my button.

How Can I pass the position variable present in the getView method to my onClick Method?
I will have several button In my View (Item view)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found, I pass my position to the ViewHolder
and I get the ViewHolder from the tag of the view or parrent view by a recursive function.
**Is there any different method?**

```
public static class ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView text01;
        public int position;
    }
    public ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v)
    {
        if(v.getTag() == null)
        {
            return getViewHolder((View)v.getParent());
        }
        return (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ViewHolder vh = getViewHolder(v);
                vh.position // Here I get position
       }
```

Comment: nice way to get the position. really helped! +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but this could help some others:

In the getView of my adapeter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ContactHolder holder = null;

        final ContactRow ContactRow = ContactRowList.get(position);

        if(row == null)
        {

         ...
         holder.delete = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.btn_contact_delete); // my button inside the item

            holder.delete.setTag(position);
         ...
        }
```

This is my listener for this button

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){

                int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
                    ((MainActivity)context).deleteContact(position,true);   // call the delete function form the main activity
            }
        });
```

My holder

```
static class ContactHolder
{
    ...
    ImageButton delete; 
}
```