# Clicking List-view row and child Button as well

Tags: android, android-listview

My **ListView's** row has one Button. Now i want to set click event to both row and button. But as i know **ListView** loose its **onItemClick** property if we set it's child click event. So please guide me a way to doing both at once

Comment: Why people down vote it.Give me reason.This was my starting question .I need explanation of down voting ,i have already accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`ListView.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29). See the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

In `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()` you're provided with the position of the item.

Comment: But In this case,The button inside the listView's row can not be clicked.i have  Listview with two { button 1,button};And i want to fire event on both button and list row

Comment: @Tofeeq: not in a simple way, that I know. I used something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234596/get-the-position-after-click-on-button-in-a-list-view), but actually I stored the info in my `CustomListItemView` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Buttons inside each list item, then set the click listener for the buttons on not on the list item.

[`Button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)

The list item clicks should go ignored and the buttons click listeners should do what you want.

Comment: But i want to click both the thing ListRow and button in the list

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to use ListView.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener) ?
Because it react instantly to a touch event. Isn't what you want?

Comment: I am using setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener) to child button of ListView.so for both its not possible to use setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener).Are you understanding my problem

Comment: I understand you can't use list.getSelectedItemPosition() with a OnTouch callback (returns -1 : I tried it).
Maybe you can show us your layout of your items in your ListView?
But what behavior of OnItemClickListener() don't you like?